# Loop_multi_select selects nothing?

Tags: python, scripting, mesh

I am trying to select a loop from an edge using loop_multi_select.

```
def loop_from_edge(edge, mesh):

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    edge.select = True
    bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring = False)
    selected_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]
    return selected_verts
```

I have also tried mode toggling based on someone's suggestion.

```
def loop_from_edge(edge, mesh):

    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    edge.select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring = False)
    selected_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]
    return selected_verts
```

The selected_verts array remains empty. I know that edge is valid and contains vertices. I am concluding that loop_multi_select isn't selecting anything, or I somehow cannot access the selected verts. How do I make loop_multi_select work?

Answer (score 3):

there are two problems :

- `edge.select = True` not working as expected because passing the edge itself doesn't work (switching modes seem to break this pointer ),you should pass the index of the edge instead
- `selected_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]` will be empty unless you switch back to object mode to update the mesh

this is the working code :

```
def loop_from_edge(edge_ind, mesh):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    mesh.edges[edge_ind].select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.loop_multi_select(ring = False)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    selected_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]
    return selected_verts
```